# How can I connect and send a message to the websocket program I wrote in C#, using the Kotlin software language?

Tags: c#, .net, android-studio, kotlin, websocket

I made a websocket program with C#. I want to connect using the Kotlin software language and print a message over Kotlin. How can I do it?

Comment: so you want to `connect to websocket using the Kotlin` and `print a message with Kotlin`? Please show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Also, please one question per post.

Comment: @nilsK I tried with okhttp3 here are my code 

https://shrib.com/#Arjun_32J4Wo

Comment: @nilsK I created a websocket with c# and I want to connect it there.

Answer (score 0):

This example (https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/WebSocketEcho.java) shows how you can open, maintain and close a connection using okhttp, as you mentioned in the comment. Sending a message looks like this:

```
webSocket.send("Hello...")
webSocket.send("...World!")
webSocket.send(ByteString.decodeHex("deadbeef"))
```

Please refer to the rest of the example for a more detailed overview.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?